# Can we encrypt MSI property values so that user cannot open the MSI/MST to see the value?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, orca, windows-application-packaging

Suppose, I have a input Password while an application is getting installed.
The application source is "MSI" and I am creating an MST file for it and providing the password in plain text as a Property=Value pair (My_Admin_Password=Password@123).
I can hide this property from the MSI logs, However if any user opens the MSI and MST from any application (InstallShield/Orca..) then he/she can see the password.
Is there any workaround for it?

I have created one PowerShell Script which only contains the command to install the MSI and I am providing the Password as an Argument and converted the PS script into EXE.
However, when we run the EXE the command and its arguments are visible in task manager(Command Line Column)

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
$credential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter your Credentials"

Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i", "path\to\your\package.msi", "/qn", "/l*vx", "installer.log", "/USERNAME=$($credential.UserName)", "/PASSWORD=$($credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)" -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Other alternative is you encrypt your password in advance and using one of the custom action in msi, you can decrypt and use accordingly.